# DDD ASP MVC validation best practices

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation

In DDD Domain model from business layer and View Model are distinct substances. And View Model represents some parts from Domain Model.

In ASP MVC DataAnnotations and Fluent Validation Library are commonly used as validation mechanism.

What are the best practices to share validation between Domain Model and View Model?

I don't like the variant with creating custom validation attribute for each property.

P.S. We can apply validation in controller manually by updating ModelState from Domain Model in Controller methods. But it will be twice  validation call (one by View Model and one by Domain Model).  May be there a simple possibility to turn off View Model validation in ASP.NET MVC Server Engine and at the same time use JS client validation.

Answer (score 4):

There is a school of thought that states "A domain entity should always be valid". In short, an entity should not contain traditional validations but rather just throw an exception if it finds itself in an invalid state. Some people may disagree with this, but that's another topic.

**Consider this real world analogy:** If a body does not eat, it dies.

In software: If a User entity does not have a firstName, it throws an exception.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't share Domain and View validations, these should be separate layers, and validations in these layers should apply to different issues.

- Validate user input in ViewModel and Controller using ViewModel DataAnnotations or FluentValidation, preferably with client side validation enabled
- Validate business/domain rules in DomainModel and Service/Business layer using custom validations
- If you have service layer providing functionality to different consumers then some redundancy of input validation can be necessary